# Incorrect syntax near 'AvayaSBCCRT'

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I'm really sorry to be asking and I'm sure it's extremely simple to answer but whenever I try to run the macro in excel below, I get the error message stated in the title:

```vb
Sub CallsMacro()

Dim ConData As ADODB.Connection
Dim rstData As ADODB.Recordset
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
Dim strServer As String
Dim strDatabase As String
Dim strFrom As String
Dim strto As String
Dim intCount As Integer

Set wsSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Refresh")
With wsSheet
strServer = "TNS-CCR-02"
strDatabase = "AvayaSBCCRT"
strFrom = .Range("C$2")
strto = .Range("C$3")
End With

Set ConData = New ADODB.Connection
With ConData
.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & strServer & ";" & "Initial Catalog=" & ";" & "persist security info=true;" & "User Id=dashboard; Password=D4$hboard;"
.CommandTimeout = 1800
.Open
End With

''Create the recordset from the SQL query
Set rstData = New ADODB.Recordset

Set wsSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Calls")

With rstData
.ActiveConnection = ConData
.Source = "SELECT DISTINCT CAST(c.createdate AS date) as [Date]," & _
"CASE WHEN c.[CategoryID] = 1 then 'Outbound' WHEN c.[CategoryID] = 2 then         'Inbound' Else 'Internal' end as [Direction], c.cli as [Number], c.ddi, 'CallCentre' as [Queue], '' as [Queue Time], u.username as [Agent], cast((c.DestroyDate - c.CreateDate) as TIME) as [Duration], 'Connected' as [Status], c.callID as [Reference]" & _
"FROM [AvayaSBCCRT].[dbo].[tblAgentActivity] as a" & _
"JOIN [AvayaSBCCRT].[dbo].[tblCallList] as c on c.calllistid = a.calllistid" & _
"JOIN [AvayaSBCCRT].[dbo].[tblUsers] as u on u.userid = a.AgentID" & _
"WHERE c.createdate between '" & strFrom & "' and '" & strto & "'" & _
"AND a.[ActivityID] = 3 "
.CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
.Open
End With

wsSheet.Activate

Dim Lastrow As Long

Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).end(xlUp).Row

Range("A2:J" & Lastrow).ClearContents

If rs.EOF = False Then wsSheet.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData


rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing


con.Close
Set con = Nothing


End Sub
```

I've looked high and low and cannot find the reason for it. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Connect to `[AvayaSBCCRT]` database in your connection string

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error. I thought it might be something to do with the query, despite the query running fine in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing spaces from the end of the lines. Your SQL contains for example:

```
[tblAgentActivity] as aJOIN [AvayaSBCCRT].[dbo].[tblCallList]
```